# Lag calculation over in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, lag, cumulative-sum

I have a table with following data: computed column : current

```
| id | Date (dd/mm/yyyy) | Factor | Actual | Current  |
|----|-------------------|--------|--------|----------|
| 1  |     04/01/2017    | 0.5    | 100    | 100      |
| 2  |     04/02/2017    | 0.5    | 120    | 100      |
| 3  |     04/03/2017    | 0.5    | 120    | 110      |
| 4  |     04/04/2017    | 0.5    | 115    | 115      |
| 5  |     04/05/2017    | 0.5    | 125    | 115      |
| 6  |     04/06/2017    | 0.5    | 100    | 120      |
| 7  |     04/07/2017    | 0.5    | 100    | 110      |
```

Current row = current of previous row + factor * (actual of previous row - current of previous row)

```
    For id = 1, current = same as actual = 100
    For id = 2, current = 100 + 0.5 * (100 - 100) = 100
    For id = 3, current = 100 + 0.5 * (120 - 100) = 110
    For id = 4, current = 110 + 0.5 * (120 - 110) = 115 
and so on...
```

How to achieve in postgresql using query?

Comment: please elaborate the post - not clear what you and how you want to get

Comment: Your calculation shows 120 as actual value for `id = 4`, but the table above that shows 115. Can you elaborate on this or fix it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - for `id = 4` get `actual` from row 3 (`actual` and `current` are from previous row).

Comment: Unless I misunderstood completely, `actual` is from the table, only `current` is computed. If you say that *`actual` and `current` are from previous row*, how come that `actual` is 115, which does not occur in the previous row?

Comment: `actual` and `current` *for calculations* are taken from previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive query.

```
with recursive my_table_with_rn as 
(
    select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
    from my_table
),

rec_query(rn, id, date, factor, actual, current) as 
(
    select rn, id, date, factor, actual, actual
    from my_table_with_rn
    where rn = 1

union all

    select 
        t.rn, t.id, t.date, t.factor, t.actual, 
        p.current + t.factor * (p.actual - p.current)
    from rec_query p
    join my_table_with_rn t on t.rn = p.rn + 1
)

select id, date, factor, actual, current
from rec_query
order by id;
```

Note, that `row_number()` was added to work in cases when `ids` are not consecutive (it's not necessary for actual data, you can use `id` instead of `rn`).

[Test it here.](http://rextester.com/XJN77506)

Comment: Thx @klin for the query